# SelectPDF HtmlPdf.ConvertHtmlString method failing in azure-"Error Occurred Trying to Start Process Chrome.exe". Side By Side config is incorrect

Tags: azure, html-pdf, selectpdf

I have a .net core 3.1 web app running in an azure web app service using selectpdf with HtmlPdf() to convert a razor view output to PDF. It has been working fine on .net 3.1. I had to upgrade the app service to .net 6 recently. Although it works in my local dev environment targeting .net 6, when run in azure web app configured with .net 6 stack, it returns an error referring to a problem starting the chromium browser engine and a side-by-side configuration issue. (See attached screen shot). Not sure why it runs in local dev environment targeting .net 6 but not in azure. Any help would be appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Per support at SelectPDF, Chromium is not officialy supported on Azure. Wasn't clear on why it's not supported, but i switched to Webkit Restricted enging running under .net 6 azure app service and this worked for me.